# Write a program that takes as close to 1 second sharp to execute in your language

Tags: code-challenge, optimization

Write a program that takes as close to 1 second Wall-time sharp to execute in your language.

Anything goes except to have the processor sleep / pause / wait, by either internal or relying on external processes.

It should be interesting to see that adding one character more somewhere will more easily bring you to the correct time (though obviously at the cost of a character). Think for example to have a for loop run 10000 instead of 1000 times which "costs" 1 character.

**Execution time** will be measured online by ideone.

I guess for an "official time", I'll run a benchmark of say 100 times. Next to a low amount of characters and close to 1.000 seconds, low variance should also earn you street creds.

It might actually be fun to come up with an idea for how much "worth" a character gets in terms of getting closer to 5.00 seconds.

Measures:

1. `abs(5 - execution_time)` (lower better)
2. Number of characters (lower better)
3. Variability (lower better)
4. Cleverness (higher better)
5. Fun (higher better)

Comment: Changed it to 1 second (from 5); don't want to torture people.

Comment: Execution times for a program can vary significantly depending upon the build and/or execution environments. Making code take a specific amount of time with any degree of accuracy requires waiting based on a time source, but the challenge currently disallows this. It seems to me that this is either an unsolvable problem in its current form or a trivially solvable one with the restriction lifted.

Comment: One second on whose computer? As Runner point's out, it will be different without using a timing device.

Comment: Good point. Which online interpreter / code executer supports most languages? I suppose they are even more variable, but hey, in the end the best plan probably does well.

Comment: [ideone](https://ideone.com) supports many languages, reports on execution time, and can be run online.

Comment: Thanks BrainSteel. I'll add that to the question. Though I do not see a timing?

Comment: What is this list of measures? Are they successive tie-breakers if scores are equal in the earlier categories? If so, none of "variability", "cleverness" and "fun" are objective, which makes them unsuitable winning criteria for PPCG. For future challenges, you might want to give [the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/8478) a try, where challenge ideas can be polished before people start working on them.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I was indeed thinking to figure out a weighted measure, or, when I added the last 2, a winner in each category. But that sandbox sounds like a good idea!

Comment: I don't see any rule disallowing for example ruby's inbuilt `Time.now`? We can't let the processor sleep/pause, but I can just keep it busy checking the current time or doing some meaningless arithmetics. `t=Time.now;loop{i=1+2;break if Time.now-t>=5.0-0.03}`

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting this? It's a wonderful idea.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI, I also like the base idea, but having the 9th revision in ~50 minutes is not really an indicator of great questions. Would be nice to be able to vote separately on the idea and on its transformation into a challenge… Then I would vote idea ▲, challenge ▼. (For now I not voted, just marked my answer community wiki, to not actually participate in this.)

Answer (score 5):

## Linux shell - 0.999 seconds (19 characters)

```
$ ping -c 2 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.049/0.053/0.057/0.004
```

I got 1000ms on the dot a few times, but 999ms was more common.  Perhaps relying on ping's inherent waits between packets to decrease network congestion may cross a line, but in my defense, I didn't write a sleep or busy-wait in my code... I just really wanted a N=2 sample size for my pings.  You never know when your sneaky computer might respond to one message and not another!

Comment: I don't see any problems. It says "anything goes except to have the processor sleep/pause".

Comment: Well, if we'd look at the processor we would know it is not "working" --> sleep/pause. And indeed, I believe it is a simple argument to ping how long it should wait.

Comment: I actually think this is one of the more clever answers for this challenge. Although (if I were remotely capable in the Linux shell, I'd post it myself), I think it would be fun to `ping -i 0 -l 1` and kill the ping as soon as the sum of `time=...` is 1000ms.

Comment: What about `0.0.0.0`?

Answer (score 2):

## Perl: 1.0031 seconds, 16 characters

(An unhandled signal terminates the process, so this code was measured from “outside” with `bash`'s `time`. Result includes the `perl` interpreter's startup time too. :()

```perl
alarm 1;1while 1
```

## Perl: 1.000059 seconds, 42 characters

(This code was surrounded with `Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()` calls for more accurate measurement.)

```perl
eval{$SIG{ALRM}=sub{die};alarm 1;1while 1}
```

(No, [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) is not a `sleep`. Not works on ideone.)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl - <s>1.0065</s> <s>1.0032</s> 1.0025 seconds

```
for ($i = 0;$i < 11489000;$i++) {
 "Hey, I can see my post from here!";
}
```

Tested using the command `time perl onesecond.pl`, and averaged.
There is also another Perl answer, so it looks like I may have to step up my game...

Comment: Quoted: "Anything goes except to have the processor sleep / pause does not count."

Comment: @PascalvKooten Sorry, must've missed that. Fixed now.

Comment: Your idea is the simple start of where I'd like to see this go!

Answer (score 0):

## **The Hexadecimal Stacking Pseudo-Assembly Language**

Probably the longest program you'll see here at 120. Ranges from (usually; there are some rare cases which are well outside this range for some reason) 0.93 to 1.03 seconds run time (I rigged up a simple timer to my copy of the java interpreter). Pushes 40,960 33s to a stack, prints them all as chars, then halts with status 418.

```
20A000
400000
000000
200021
400100
410000
400200
200001
400000
410200
400000
220000
420000
400000
030000
010001
010000
000001
140100
0401A2
```

Comment: ...on your machine. Does it run equally fast on other peoples machines?

Comment: No clue. That's the problem with this challenge unfortunately.